# Error response from successful JSONP call

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, web-services

I've created a Cross Origin compatible WCF Service (which took me 4 days of research!) well I've got everything working but now I have a problem with the jQuery request. It's giving me an error I don't know anything about.

Can someone give me an idea on what to do here.

my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet',
    data: 's=boo!',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(res) {
        alert('yay');
    },
    error: function(a,b,c) {
    alert(a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
    }
});
</script>
```

the error response:

> [object Object], parsererror, Error:
>   jQuery17206724130902069609_1340034989481 was not called

If I go to the browser and enter the URL I get:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">OK</string>
```

Can someone shed some light here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be returning a javascript call from that page. that is how jsonp works.

so the response should look something like this:

```
jQuery17206724130902069609_1340034989481('some param');
```

and by default jquery will add the param called `callback` to the url which specifies the above callback name that the server should respond with.

i recommend reading the [ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), especially the sections dealing with jsonp. and looking up how [jsonp works](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)

**spoon feeding start:**

make your server respond with:

```
iwillreaduponjsonp({'status':'ok'});
```

make your jsonp request in the clientside like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet',
    data: 's=boo!',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "iwillreaduponjsonp",
    success: function(res) {
        alert('yay');
    },
    error: function(a,b,c) {
    alert(a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
    }
});
```

**/spoon feeding end**

Comment: you can start by not responding with xml

Comment: OK now I've changed the service to respond with JSON, so it now returns "OK" yet I'm still receiving the same error

Comment: you must not be reading my response. you need to have the server respond with a javascript call. ill edit my answer with greater degree of spoon feeding